# C# Showing which series a data point is from when clicking on it in Plot model (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a GUI which is filled with different plot models, so space is limited. In the example image there are four different series and i have clicked on one point (where the arrow is pointing). This makes a box show up with X and Y info, I was wondering if it was possible to show which series the datapoint is from in the box as well. I have attempted to use Tooltips but I have not been able to understand how they work. If anyone could offer a hand that would be great.

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You can add a title to the series by just doing plot.series.Title = "etc". This will add a title to the X,Y box